# How to sign up on a website which is a flutter app using selenium?

Tags: python, flutter, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to sign up on a site which is a flutter app but i am not able to find elements as I do in simple websites. How to do this. Here is the website on which i am trying [UGCLISTS](https://app.ugclists.com/signup).
How to enter values in these fields and click the buttons. Is there any efficient way to do this.